# Can I use more than 3 parts in my Android applicationId?

Tags: android, google-play-console, app-search

Can I use more than 3 parts in my Android applicationId like `com.polanji.learning.english.reading.writting.listening.speaking.grammar.vocabulary`?

Is it good or bad practice for ASO? Is there any kind of issue if I use more than 3 parts?

Comment: use product flavor feature for that